# Drupal Custom Widget not saving form field value

Tags: entities

I am trying to add a Custom Element to the Webform  Content Type  and save it in the Webform(table) column (group_id)

Here is the Webform Custom Field which list all the groups as tree and does not save to node on submit

http://pastebin.com/nsSzyT06

```
[field_webform_group] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

When I compare this with the summary field.The webfrom custom field does not include a storage form state

Comment: Do you want to create a custom component for the webform?

Comment: I have alter the webform table to save group_id. And the Webfrom content type to show the groups. I need to save the field value to the webform column group_id. I have created a widgets and element to list the group

Comment: @SumitMadan http://pastebin.com/nsSzyT06 here is the working code. But I need to know If I am doing anything wrong in the code. After creating the field schema in the install file it was saving to the node